# How to subset rows with strings

Tags: r, function

I want to use `function` for repetitively making up set with different names.

for example, if I have 5 random vectors.

```
number1<-sample(1:10, 3)
number2<-sample(1:10, 3)
number3<-sample(1:10, 3)
number4<-sample(1:10, 3)
number5<-sample(1:10, 3)
```

Then, I will use these vectors for selecting rows in raw data set(i.e. dataframe)

```
testset1<-raw[number1,]
testset2<-raw[number2,]
testset3<-raw[number3,]
tsetset4<-raw[number4,]
testset5<-raw[number5,]
```

It takes lot of spaces in manuscript for writing up each commands. I'm trying to shorten these commands with using 'function'

However, I found that it is hard to use variables in a function statement for writing 'text argument'. For example, it is easy to use variables like this.

```
mean_function<-function(x){
mean(x)
}
```

But, I want to use function like this.

```
testset "number with 1-5" <-raw[number"number 1-5",]
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create a function for this task, simply use `lapply` to loop over the list of elements produced by `mget()`, then set some names and finally put all results in the global environment:

```
rowSelected <-lapply(mget(paste0("number", 1:5)), function(x) raw[x, ])
names(rowSelected) <- paste0("testset", 1:5)
list2env(rowSelected, envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thanks! it really helped.

Comment: @김은산 if this answer solved your problem, then consider mark it as 'accepted' by doing clic on the tick mark right below the score.